# AWS ElasticSearch Query for Keyword not getting results I expect

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query that looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "Message.keyword": "*System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "Message.keyword": "*system.net.webclient).downloadfile(*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a Doc in my Index that includes:

```
message:Engine state is changed from None to Available. Details: NewEngineState=Available PreviousEngineState=None SequenceNumber=13 HostName=ConsoleHost HostVersion=5.1.18362.628 HostId=3dd1a50a-cc15-45e0-bf63-4456d556fb67 HostApplication=powershell.exe -command PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download EngineVersion=5.1.18362.628 RunspaceId=de762b62-056c-4be1-90bf-a12cfe6fbc72
```

As you can see above it includes:

> (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https:....

It seems like the filter here should be matching the message, but when I execute the Query through Kibana, nothing matches even though I can see the doc above inside my index through Kibana UI if I just query for `*.`

I think maybe this is because the query above is querying for `Message.keyword`? How do I get it to successfully `hit` the document above?

**Edit:**

mapping: https://pastebin.com/cWN4jF3d

Sample data: https://pastebin.com/SyErqaG8

Comment: r u able to resolve ur issue, I saw u posted something and then deleted

Comment: Could you please share your ES mapping and data sample

Comment: @alexgids, 


mapping: https://pastebin.com/cWN4jF3d



Data sample in my index (specific doc I expected to hit): https://pastebin.com/SyErqaG8

Comment: @Opster ES Ninja, unfortunately, the answer I gave to myself was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for the query not returning the result:

1. The field name in mapping is `message` whereas in query you are using `Message`.
2. A field with `keyword` datatype index the data as it is. This means it will be case sensitive as well. The document you shared has text `System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(` where you can see that there are characters with upper case whereas the search query you expect to match `"*system.net.webclient).downloadfile(*"` has all lower case characters.

Therefore the query should be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "message.keyword": "*System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "message.keyword": "*System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, during my investigations before, I tried changing cases. However, it still produces no result. I used the query you kindly fixed and put it into Kibana filter through discover->add filter for my index (https://imgur.com/a/55sm7lk). It produced on results unfortunately. What's weird is that if I type in "message: System.Net.WebClient" in the Kibana search box, it shows correct results (https://imgur.com/oY3cQZy). Any additional advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Another note, I tried querying for something like :

 "wildcard": {
                "message.keyword": "*WebClient*"
              }

And it showed no result either.

Answer (score 0):

The *keyword* fields are used only for exact match. You will need to match the regular fields if you only want to match a substring / subset of the string, by querying on **Message** instead of **Message.keyword**:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "Message": "*System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "Message": "*system.net.webclient).downloadfile(*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo rthe reply, does this mean I can never use regular expression/wildcard to match keyword field?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that you can't use regular expression/wildcard to match keyword field, rather it means whatever regex you provide should match the whole field:
e.g. Lets say you have the following field in ES called `message` with value "aa bb cc" then the following query will match it:
`message.keyword: *bb*`